# What's wrong with how I calculated the inverse of this matrix?

Tags: matrices

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & -1 & 2 & | & 1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 0 & | & 0 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 0 & | & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right) $ is the original matrix. Now, add 2*R1 to R2 and R3.

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & -1 & 2 & | & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 4 & | & 2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 4 & | & 2 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right) $ Now, add -R3 to R2.

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & -1 & 2 & | & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 0 & | & 0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 4 & | & 2 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right) $ Now, add -.5*R3 to R1.

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & -1 & 0 & | & 0 & 0 & -.5\\
0 & -2 & 0 & | & 2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 4 & | & 2 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right) $ Now, add -.5*R2 to R1.

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 & 0 & | & -1 & -.5 & -.5\\
0 & -2 & 0 & | & 2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 4 & | & 2 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right) $ Now, simple division yields

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & | & 1 & .5 & .5\\
0 & 1 & 0 & | & -1 & -.5 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & | & .5 & 0 & .25\end{array} \right) $

Comment: something weird happened between line 3 and 4; you should only be modifying R1, but R2 (the "right-hand part" of R2) is modified in this step

Comment: What happened on line 4? I can't really see what you've done to the right hand side.

Comment: I think that was my mistake.

Comment: Yep, sometimes we are blind to our own simple mistakes (or at least I am).

Comment: between line three and four, R2 was mysteriously affected. I feel like a hero!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff is there something unacceptable about this question? It seems to demonstrate effort and seeks understanding rather than a simple "do it for me" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you made a small computational error in rewriting the right hand inverse matrix after step 3. You gotta be really careful about that,it's like a complicated integration-it can really shaft you on an exam or important homework problem. If a row reduction to yield an inverse matrix looks wrong to you but you're not sure if you made a mistake, you can always multiply the matrix by the obtained inverse. If you made a mistake, you won't get the identity matrix and row where the mistake is is where you won't have a 1 or a 0 usually. Even better,if you've got access to a computer algebra system like *Mathematica*, that'll make checking really quick and simple.